# Read data, update then write back to DB by Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on data processing using spark and cassandra.

What I want to do is read and load the data from cassandra first. Process the data and write them back to cassandra.

When spark does the map function, an error occurs - `Row is read-only <class 'Exception'>`

Here is my method. Showing as the below

```
def detect_image(image_attribute):
    image_id = image_attribute['image_id']
    image_url = image_attribute['image_url']

    if image_attribute['status'] is None:
         image_attribute['status'] = Status()
    image_attribute['status']['detect_count'] += 1

    ... # the other item assignment
```

```
cassandra_data = sql_context.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="photo",
                                                                                         keyspace="data").load()

cassandra_data_processed = cassandra_data.rdd.map(process_batch_image)

cassandra_data_processed.toDF().write \
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
        .mode('overwrite') \
        .options(table="photo", keyspace="data") \
        .save()
```

The error of `Row is read-only <class 'Exception'>` are in line
`image_attribute['status'] = Status()` and 
`image_attribute['status']['detect_count'] += 1`

is it necessary to copy the `image_attribute` to be a new object? However, the image_attribute is a nested objects. It will be so hard to copy one by one layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion is absolutely right. The map function converts an incoming type to another type. That is at least thr intention. The incoming object is immutable to make this operation idempotent. I guess there is no way around copying the image objects (manually or using something like `deepcopy`)

Hope that helps

Comment: How about I create a new object to do the data processing and update by batch update query using cassandra-driver instead of df.write()?
Will the performance be bad in this case?

Comment: That sounds like a valid approach. I would give it a try